# Swap last.first to first.last in text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to swap two words in a string.  I currently have a txt file with a column of users formatted `last.first`.  How can I swap that to `first.last`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty - minimal error checking...

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | 
  ForEach-Object {  
    if  ( $_.Contains('.') ) {
      $_.Split('.')[1] + '.' + $_.Split('.')[0]  } 
    else { $_ } 
  }
```

Comment: exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

`-split` the string and concatenate:

```
$Last,$First = "Lastname.Firstname" -split '\.'
$newString = "$First.$Last"
```

or use `-replace` to reorder the two:

```
"Lastname.Firstname" -replace '(\w+)\.(\w+)','$2.$1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gc .\names.txt |% { "{1}.{0}" -f $_.split('.') }
```

- Get the lines out of the file with `gc` which is an alias for `Get-Content`
- Loop over them with `%` which is an alias for `ForEach-Object`
- [`Split()`](http://ss64.com/ps/split.html) each line around the full stop, into an array of two items
- Use the [`"" -f` string formatting](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) operator to build a string taking array items in the order 1, 0 which swaps the order of the parts.

Comment: You can make this answer more useful by adding text explaining what this code does and how it solves the problem. Answers that teach are much more useful than code without explanation. [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13023989)